# lucene.net problem with wildcard "*"

Tags: lucene.net

hello i have a question to lucene searching syntax

the "*" is a wildcard.
when i search  te*  : i find test ,... 
but when i search *st  i don't find "test :>
whats the issue?

and i have a search concerning the text and an other search concerning the filename

in the filename search i use "*"+searchstring "*"
in the textsearch just "searchstring"

what can i do when i search both, but filename with "*" "*"

```
parser = New MultiFieldQueryParser(New [String]() {"title", "bodytext"}, New StandardAnalyzer())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm
http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches
-->Note: You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search.

well i think that's it :/

Answer (score 1):

The default setting in the QueryParser is to not allow leading wildcards.

You can alter this with setting property on the QueryParser -  SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

Be aware though the performance can take a major tumble since you potentially open up a huge number of hits with this kind of wildcard search.

Roger